# How to iterate and apply text pre processing on sublists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a corpus of 20k rows of twitter data, which I have already lower cased and tokenised using tweet tokenizer.

For example:

```
X = [
  ["i","love,"to","play","games","","."],
  ["my","favourite,"colour","is","purple","!"],
  ["@ladygaga","we,"love","you","#stan","'someurl"]
]
```

```
tweet_tokens = []

for tweet in tweets:
    tweet = tweet.lower()
    tweet_tokens.append(tweet)
```

This is how I lowercased my tokens.

How can I iterate through the sublists to append each lists to remove stopwords, punctuation, blank spaces and URLs but keep the content of @'s.

This is what I thought/tried but its not giving me the right results (only showing stop words for an example)

```
filtered_sentence = []
filtered_word = []

for sent in X:
    for word in sent:
        if word not in stopwords:
            filtered_word.append(word)
            filtered_sentence.append(word)
```

What would be the correct way to iterate through each sublists, process without disrupting the lists.

Ideally the output should look like this

```
Cleaned_X = [
  ["love,"play","games"],
  ["favourite,"colour","purple",],
  ["ladygaga","love","#stan"]
]
```

Comment: So you want to create a new list containing lists that no longer contain certain elements. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import validators
punctuation_list = ['(',')',';',':','[',']',',', '!' ,'?','.', "", '']

dirty = [
  ["i","love","to","play","games","","."],
  ["my","favourite","colour","is","purple","!"],
  ["@ladygaga","we","love","you","#stan","https://test.de"]
]

def clean_list_list(tweets):
    return [[elem for elem in tweet if elem_check(elem)]
           for tweet in tweets]
def tweet_check(elem):
    return elem not in punctuation_list and not validators.url(elem)
clean_list_list(dirty)
```

I have testet this, it should be very close to the solution you are looking for.

output

```
[['i', 'love', 'to', 'play', 'games'],
 ['my', 'favourite', 'colour', 'is', 'purple'],
 ['@ladygaga', 'we', 'love', 'you', '#stan']]
```

You can write your own validate function if you want to or use validators:

```
pip install validators
```

Comment: Thank you Natan! it works! i am unable to use validators but i will look into regex and other methods of doing further cleaning! have a great day!

Comment: are you unable because you haven't used pip install before or because that is not a solution for your project? I added the pip install command above.

Comment: yea im not allowed to use other libraries, only build in libraries like re, string etc.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

x = [
["i","love", "to","play","games","","."],
["my","favourite", "colour","is","purple","!"],
["@ladygaga","we", "love","you","#stan","'someurl"]
]

```
punctuations = ['(',')',';',':','[',']',',', '!' ,'?','.', "", '']
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

clean_list = []
for sub_list in x:
    for word in sub_list:
        if word not in stop_words and word not in punctuations:
            clean_list.append(word)
print(clean_list)
```

Output:

```
['love', 'play', 'games', 'favourite', 'colour', 'purple', '@ladygaga', 'love', '#stan', "'someurl"]
```

Comment: hi thanks for your input, but i i want to keep the sublists. so the output should be [['love', 'play', 'games'],[ 'favourite', 'colour', 'purple'], ['@ladygaga', 'love', '#stan', "'someurl"]] - any idea how to do this?